# How to do a conditional mask on a field with angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mask

I'm developing a multi-language app, and my date fields must have a conditional mask according to the language.
For the language, I'm using pascalprecht.translate (https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) and for the mask I'm using ngMask (https://github.com/candreoliveira/ngMask).

My problem is: when the user set the page language to en-use, the mask on my field must be 9999-99-99 and when the user set the language to pt-br, the mask on my field must be 99/99/9999

Is there a way to do it dinamically? Without create two fields and show the field according to the language?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did it when I stop using jQuery to do my masks and started to use this awesome library: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

It really saves my life!